# JQuery Alter CSS Value of Left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to move a div Left a specified amount of pixels I'm using a slider that I got from here:

http://carpe.ambiprospect.com/slider/archive/v1.3/

So from the example my div looks like this:

```
<div class="horizontal_slider"
        id="your_slider_id"
        style="left: 0px;"
        onmousedown="slide(event, 'your_slider_id',
        'horizontal', 100, 0, 100, 101,
        0, 'your_display_id');" >&nbsp;</div>
```

And If I adjust left: 0px the slider the move along its line, I've been trying to alter the left from an ajax response that looks like this:

```
var stateofmindint = $.ajax({ url: "function.php?state=1", async: false }).responseText;
```

And I try to change its Left style like this:

```
$("#your_slider_id").css({"left": stateofmindint +"px"});
```

But for some reason it stays at Left:0px, I've tried to remove the style tag in the div, but to no effect, I also tried referencing the class instead of the ID but nothing seems to be working! I am definitely getting a value everytime through ajax. Any advice would help thank you!

Comment: That looks correct. Check what the `stateofmindint` variable actually contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with an alert/console.log what's the response of your ajax script or try setting "stateofmindint" to a known value in code to test what part has the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Theres something weird going on. On that page you link I tried using firebugs console to see the sliders left value with the following

```
$("#horizontal_slider_2").css("left", "30px");
```

But jQuery returns null with that selector. The following works:

```
document.getElementById('horizontal_slider_2').style.left = '30px';
```

So theres some bug going on with jQuery or that slider code

Answer (score 0):

missing a "+" for your concatenation? looks like your syntax is off

css({"left": stateofmindint +"px"});

should be?

css({"left:" + stateofmindint +"px"});

Comment: No, it shouldn't. An object literal is in the form `{ "name": value }`.

Comment: That is right, he is using css with an object, so "left" is the key and stateofmindint + "px" is the value. This allows for multiple assignment, though it should be faster when called as css('left', stateofmindint + "px")